# Setting up a MPV environment for developing scripts?

Tags: windows, mpv

I am delving into writing scripts for MPV.

I am struggling with isolating my actual every day MPV executable (and its `/appdata/mpv` files) from an MPV that that I want to use strictly for developing and testing scripts.

```
c:\users\Ralf\Documents\MPV\Mpv.exe
c:\users\Ralf\Documents\MPV-Dev\Mpv.exe
```

For example currently both the of the above MPV executables load script files from `/appdata/mpv/scripts`. Is it possible to get `.\MPV-Dev\Mpv.exe` to read scripts from a folder like:

```
c:\users\Ralf\Documents\MPV-Dev\scripts
```

or just get it to all together to look at another folder in place of  `/appdata/mpv`.

Currently I cant freely edit the files at `/appdata/mpv` as I would like to, as my main MPV copy is relying on it

Any help would be greatly appreciated!